# Resharper Jumping to implementation of Interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Resharper 8.2 in VS2013

In MVC the IoC running creates an instance of an Interface.

So , in my controller I get:

```
orderManager.DoOrder(...);
```

which is an **IOrder** object.

Works good.

When my cursor is on orderManager.**DoOrder**, how do I jump to the actual code behind DoOrder, not the interface .

PEEK'ing gives me the interface and all the Go To commands give me the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your chosen keyboard layout. I Use Ctrl+F12. Look for "Go to implementation" in the below short cuts. Also, Try Ctrl+Shift+Alt+B

[Resharper Keyboard Shortcuts](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Keyboard_Shortcuts.html)

Comment: That's Go To File Member in my mapping (using the old 2.0 maps) What's the name of the command, perhaps I can look it up that way

Comment: Strangely I get "Implementations of DoOrder are not found". WHich is not true

Comment: I'm assuming the implementation is in a referenced assembly? If you are using reflection etc it isn't clever enough..

Comment: Hmm, no, project contains all the implementations and another contains all the interfaces. Really simple code.

Comment: I'm just updating to the latest build to check. In Resharper > Options > General menu clear your cache from all options. Restart visual studio and reopen your solution. See if that helps.

Comment: It appears to be a bug, I've tried each of those options. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-380442